# SSRS Report Split by User

Tags: email, reporting-services, subscription

We have an SSRS report that needs to be sent to users based on the e-mail address in the report.  The catch is that each user should only be able to see their own records.  For example, a report has 10 total records with 4 of them for John Smith and 6 of them for Jane Smith.  The subscription should e-mail John only his 4 records and Jane should only receive her 6 records.  The options in the subscriptions page do not seem to accommodate this but I wanted to make sure.

The report itself contains the e-mail address of the recipients.

We are using version 13.0.5850.14

Comment: Do you have the Enterprise Edition of SQL Server? The Data Driven Subscriptions are made for this functionality. If not you'd need to create a Stored Procedure or write some VBA or C# code to do it.

Comment: Not sure how to check exactly but I do have the option to create a data driven subscription.  I looked at a couple of guides but they do not seem to do what I need it to do.

Comment: Your report needs a parameter to filter by (you say email addr). The Data Driven (DD) query would query the same table to get list of employees's record along with the email address to send to. In the DD subscription, you set the report parameter to use the email address in the DD query to filter each report by the employee's email address. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/lesson-3-defining-a-data-driven-subscription?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thank you!  That did the trick!!  Not sure how to mark it as the answer however.  Maybe I'm too new?

Comment: It wasn't much of an answer - I just pointed you in the right direction. I suppose you could upvote the comment.